# Build libVLC for Android - make libxml2 error 77

Tags: vlc, libvlc, vlc-android

command to build:

```
buildsystem/compile.sh -l -a all -r
```

last logs:

> configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-minimal checking
> whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
> checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu checking host system
> type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi checking for a BSD-compatible
> install... /usr/bin/install -c checking whether build environment is
> sane... yes checking for arm-linux-androideabi-strip...
> arm-linux-androideabi-strip checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p...
> /bin/mkdir -p checking for gawk... gawk checking whether make sets
> $(MAKE)... yes checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
> checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
> checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc...
> /home/test/Android/Sdk/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi17-clang
> checking whether the C compiler works... no configure: error: in
> `/home/test/Downloads/vlc/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/contrib-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libxml2': configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables See` config.log' for more details make: *** [../src/libxml2/rules.mak:51:
> .libxml2] Error 77

How can I solve this issue?

SDK latest 30,
NDK r21,
latest cloned vlc andorid git version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the docker image and follow CI steps.

Comment: I do not really know docker, so I don't what to do with it. Why I can't just build it without correctly. I remember I did it ok on Ubuntu, but now I have Linux Mint and there is such issue

Comment: It may be less painful to learn the basics to be able to use the provided docker image than to get and maintain your local environment to be just right.

Comment: I downloaded https://code.videolan.org/videolan/docker-images/-/tree/master/vlc-debian-android and built it (`Successfully built c7c86c332bb1`) but what to do next?

Comment: run it and build inside the container

Comment: can you please write example commands how to do it, please?